# Java: search the nearest value in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of ordered double of big dimension, for example:

```
[2.1,3.4,3.6,4.1]
```

Now I generate, in some manner, a double numer, for example:

```
3.51
```

I need to make a function in Java that get the array and the number and give me the nearest value in the array of this number. In this example 3.6.

How i can do this in the most efficent way ? Because I can have array of 300000 double and need to do this operation frequently. Then i can't make a simple compare.

**Edit:**
I have make this, in some test the result is correct, for you is correct?

```
        int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(allTime.times, value);
        double out;

        if(pos >= 0)
        {
//          System.out.println(allTime.times[pos]);
            out = allTime.times[pos];
        }
        else if(pos == -1)
        {
//          System.out.println(allTime.times[0]);
            out = allTime.times[0];
        }
        else
        {
            int insertionPoint = -pos-1;
            if(insertionPoint < allTime.times.length)
            {
                if(allTime.times[insertionPoint] - value < value - allTime.times[insertionPoint-1])
//                  System.out.println(allTime.times[insertionPoint] );
                    out = allTime.times[insertionPoint];
                else
//                  System.out.println(allTime.times[insertionPoint-1] );
                    out = allTime.times[insertionPoint-1];
            }
            else
//              System.out.println(allTime.times[allTime.times.length -1]);
                out = allTime.times[allTime.times.length -1];
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at TreeSet ceiling, floor, higher and lower methods.

Comment: if the array is big(and not ordered) then give some hand of GPU

Comment: If the array is ordered, you should use binary search *O(log n)* if it is not ordered you need to read the hole array *O(n)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jimmy T answer is not handling the corner case, like if the searching number falls before 0th index or if it falls beyond the last index.

Here is the corrected one

```
     double searchNearest(double[] array, double searchNumber) {
    int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(array, searchNumber);
    if (pos >= 0)
        return searchNumber;
    else {
        int insertionPoint = -pos - 1;
        if (insertionPoint > 0 && insertionPoint < array.length) {
            if ((searchNumber - array[insertionPoint - 1]) < (array[insertionPoint] - searchNumber)) {
                return array[insertionPoint - 1];
            } else {
                return array[insertionPoint];
            }

        } else {

            return insertionPoint == 0 ? array[0] : array[array.length - 1];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `insertionPoint` cannot be smaller than zero.

Comment: If you enter 1.1 in above data, insertionPoint will be -1. isn't?

Comment: `pos` will be -1. `insertionPoint` will be `-(-1) - 1` which results in `0`.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.binarySearch` also works for elements not contained in the array.

```
int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, value);
```

If the value is not contained it returns a negative value which describes where the value should be: `(-(insertion point) - 1)`.

Then just find which of the two neighbor values is the correct.

```
if(pos < 0)
{
  int insertionPoint = -pos-1;
  if(insertionPoint == arr.length) //value is bigger than every value in array
    //arr[insertionPoint-1] is the nearest value
  else if(insertionPoint == 0) //value is smaller than every value in array
    //arr[0] is the nearest value
  else if(value-arr[insertionPoint-1] < arr[insertionPoint]-value)
    //arr[insertionPoint-1] is the nearest value
  else
    //arr[insertionPoint] is the nearest value
}else
  //arr[pos] has the same value
```

The value at index `insertPoint` is bigger than `value`. I also handled the case that the value is contained in the array.